# What is the "instances" list in AWS Lambda? Cannot call Sagemaker Inference Endpoint From AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I am very new to AWS so please bear with my question.

I trained a model on Sagemaker Notebook, deployed it as an endpoint, and can see my predictions by hitting the endpoint from within the Sagemaker notebook. The code to create and return a prediction from my endpoint within my notebook is:

```
data = json.dumps({"input1": "hello world"})
model.predict(data)


{'predictions': [[0.15274021,
   0.225715473,
   0.460293412,
   0.127488852,
   0.0337620787]]}
```

Now I want to make my endpoint useable by my other applications, and saw that I could do this with AWS Lambda and API Gateway. In Lambda, I have successfully connected my `ENDPOINT_NAME` and am actually hitting my endpoint, but am struggling to get a 200 response due to request payload issues.

```
def lambda_handler(utterance, context):
    payload = json.dumps({"input1": utterance})
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME, ContentType='application/json',Body=payload)
```

I pasted most of the error message below

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message \"{\n    \"error\": \"Failed to process element: 0 key: input1 of 'instances' list. Error: INVALID_ARGUMENT: JSON object: does not have named input: input1\"\n}\".",
}
```

What is this `instances` list? What should my input format be for lambda? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the SageMaker TensorFlow container without an inference.py?

Have you tried:

```
payload = json.dumps({"instances": utterance})
```